# Python: searching csv and return entire row

Tags: python, csv, search, return, row

I couldn´t find a better place to ask my question. I am learning Python and trying to create a script as follows.

1) Should be able to search csv file.

2) Return entire row if match is found.

My csv:

```
Product,Scan,Width,Height,Capacity
LR,2999,76,100,17.5
RT,2938,37,87,13.4
```

If I search for 2938 for an example, entire row is returned as follows:

```
Product: RT
Scan: 2938
Width: 37
Height: 87
Capacity: 13,4
```

So far I have:

```
csvFile = getComponent().filePath
pos = csvFile.rfind('Desktop\\')
csvFile = csvFile[:pos] + 'programm\\products.csv'

myfile = open(csvFile)
myfile.seek(0)
for line in myfile.split('\n'):
    data = line.split(',')
    print data
    if data[2] == agv_O_Cal.value and data[3] == agv_O_Mod.value:
        print 'found: value = %s' %agv_O_Cal.value, agv_O_Mod.value
        Product = data[5]
        Scan = data[6]
        Width = data[7]
        Height = data[9]
        Capacity = data[10]
        print , Product, Scan, Width, Height, Capacity
```

The solution doesn´t work.

Comment: whats your current output?

Comment: Indetation error: unexpected indent

Comment: I edit your code. try that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

#input number you want to search
number = raw_input('Enter number to find\n')

#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('test.csv', "r"), delimiter=",")


#loop through the csv list
for row in csv_file:
    #if current rows 2nd value is equal to input, print that row
    if number == row[1]:
         print (row)
```

Comment: Should my csv file be located in the same folder as py file?

Comment: yes, ofcourse replace "test.csv" with your csv name

Comment: Enter number to find
2938
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\programm\phy2.py", line 5, in <module>
    csv_file = csv.reader(open('autod.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined

Comment: How is possible to output as a list? Description before (ex. Product: Xcl where Xcl is value taken from csv) and value after.

Comment: didnt understand your question, but please upvote/accept my answer as per community standards.

Comment: What if I want to search all columns? Is it possible to search realtime? Is it possible to return results as a list?

Comment: yes it is, think about it, try things then if you need help post on here for help

Comment: I got this error @smushi

  File "fil.py", line 17
    print row
            ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(row)?

Comment: `csv.reader(open('test.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")` - change rb to r in this line. It gave me this error without it. `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes`

Comment: @Kevin Nguyen, in Python3, the print became a callable, so you have to type `print(row)` instead of `print row` which worked fine in Python2

Answer (score 1):

you can use `csv` module like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open(csvFile, 'r'))
for data in reader:
    #list index start from 0, thus 2938 is in data[1]
    if data[1] == agv_O_Cal.value and data[3] == agv_O_Mod.value:
        #do somethinngs
```